Question about the example correctness of polynomial time reducibility
in here, when the answer tries to answer about the property of
polynomial time reduction, in the last paragraph it writes:

However, Polynomial-time reductions are not symmetric. That is, it is not true that  $A \le_p B \implies B \le_p A$
. Consider for example a binary alphabet, $A = \{0,1\}^*$
, and B = {0}
. The function $f(x) =0$
is a valid polynomial-time reduction from $A$
to $B$,
but there is no polynomial-time reduction from $B$
to $A$
.

I'm confused by this example, first $A = \{0,1\}^*$
means arbitrary length binary string, right? like $010, 1011, 01011$ etc,
including empty string?
When taking $f(x)=0$, how can $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$ be satisfied?
$x \in A \implies f(x) \in B$ is easy,
but for $f(x) \in B \implies x \in A$,
if $f(x) \in B$, how do we know which $x \in A$, this confuses me,
x is not unique?
Also, there exist a polynomial-time reduction from $B$ to $A$,
just take $0$ to $0$,  $0 \in B \iff 0 \in A$,
so I think the statement should be there's polynomial-time reduction from
$B$ to $A$, but no polynomial-time reduction from $A$ to $B$.
Confused, could someone answer for me?

In the context of reduction functions, the implied domain (and codomain) is usually $\Sigma^*$. Assuming that $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ (i.e. assuming that we're not dealing with some larger alphabet that happens to have 0 and 1 in it), it follows that $A = \Sigma^*$, so the domain of $f$ is all of A. Thus, for every $x$ where it is valid to write $f(x)$, we already know that $x \in A$, before we even look at B.
As for your proposed reverse reduction: What does your function do with values which are not 0?

Hello, my understanding is reduction is convert from problem $A$ to problem $B$, $f(x)$ won't occupy all of $B$. Say 3SAT poly-reduces to Independent Set, and Independent Set poly-reduces to Set Cover. Every 3SAT can be think of kind of a Set Cover problem, but not every Set Cover problem could be think of 3SAT problem. That's why I think it's B reduce to A, but not A reduce to B.

@pokerresources: I'm not sure you understand what A and B are. A is the set of strings for which your algorithm should say "yes" (or true), and the complement of A (with respect to $\Sigma^$) is the set of strings for which your algorithm should say "no" (or false). Since $A = \Sigma^$, the algorithm for solving A is just "return true," so it's not a useful algorithm for solving any problem. Nothing reduces to A, except for problems which are isomorphic to A (i.e. other problems whose solution is a trivial "return true"). Since B is not trivial, B does not reduce to A.

I may need to wrap my head to understand $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$. $f$ is not injective, so when $f(x) \in B$, how do we know which $x \in A$, or we don't care?Also, if $B={0,1}$, $f(x)=0$ is a poly-reduction from $A$ to $B$, and $f(x)=1$ is also a poly-reduction from $A$ to $B$, $f(x)=random choose either 0 or 1$ is also  a poly-reduction from $A$ to $B$?

@pokerresources: The whole statement is (impliedly) guarded by $\forall x \in \Sigma^*$, so it's every x (both in A and not, because the implication must run both ways). Random choice is not normally allowed as part of a Turing machine, because the definition of a Turing machine has no means of producing random numbers. But you can certainly pick an arbitrary value.

I have redefined it more mathematically. Yes, The double implies leads one astray.

@Kevin still confused by $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$, let's take $B={0}$ again, when $f(x) \in B$, I want to conclude $x \in A$, but how do I know which $x$? Since $f$ is not injective.

@pokerresources: You are trying to read the mathematical formula as an algorithm (a set of instructions that tells you how to transform one value into another). It is not. It is a statement, which must be true for all possible values of x. There is no such thing as "knowing which x," because the statement must be true no matter what x we choose. For every x whose image is in B, that x must be in A. If more than one x has an image in B, then all of them must be in A.

Ok. I looked up the definition in Sipser. More mathematically, $A \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and $B \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma = \{1,0\}$.
A polynomial-time reduction from $A$ to $B$ is defined

If there exists a function $f: \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$  s.t if $x \in A$, then  $f(x) \in B$ AND if $x \notin A$ then $f(x) \notin B$  for all elements of A (by defn. of a function).

Note that mathematically, $f(x)$ can take only a single value in the co-domain. So, In the example above, if $B = \{0\}$, then the reverse reduction, call it $g$, can take utmost only one value of $A$ if it exists for the element $0$. So, If $x \notin B$, there is NO guarantee that the generated $g(x)$ is NOT in $A$.


The definition of $\Sigma$ you have given is not the conventional notation. We normally would have $\Sigma = {0, 1}$ and instead write $\Sigma^*$ in the appropriate places. 2. There is no general requirement that $f$ is injective, but your definition implicitly requires it because you refer to $f^{-1}$, which does not exist for non-injective f. 3. Your explanation of g looks wholly incorrect to me. Reductions are not required to be surjective. The problem with g is that it must map values other than 0 to something that is not an element of A, but there is no such object in the codomain.


Thanks! How about now?

@kevin After reviewing your comment since Reductions are not required to be surjective, I removed that requirement. Please check if this is ok & upvote please. I think this will be useful for Math majors
